# Net Core MVC Dockeri file not working.There is no error my local project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, n-layer

I have net core mvc project running in layered architecture. It works fine locally but not with docker

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./MyBlog.Shared/MyBlog.Shared.csproj ./MyBlog.Shared/
COPY ./MyBlog.Data/MyBlog.Data.csproj ./MyBlog.Data/
COPY ./MyBlog.Services/MyBlog.Services.csproj ./MyBlog.Services/
COPY ./MyBlog.Entities/MyBlog.Entities.csproj ./MyBlog.Entities/
COPY ./MyBlog.Mvc/MyBlog.Mvc.csproj ./MyBlog.Mvc/
COPY MyBlog.sln .
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish ./MyBlog.Mvc/MyBlog.Mvc.csproj -o /publish/
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","MyBlog.Mvc.dll" ]
```

[image: Layers Image]

[image: Dockerfile debug Image]

[image: Dockerfile output Image]

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the app listening to `localhost` only. You need to set an environment variable to tell ASP.NET Core to listen to all interfaces, instead of just `localhost` which is inaccessible to host.

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+"
```

You have a `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:5000"` command, but it doesn't seem to take effect, try specifying it as argument:

```
docker run 
  --rm -it 
  -p 8000:80 
  -p 8001:443 
  -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" 
  -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 
  -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="password" 
  -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=\https\aspnetapp.pfx 
  -v %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https:C:\https\ 
  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
```

See Microsoft's docs on how to dockerize an ASP.NET Core app.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thank you , i will try your suggestions